# Jquery get width of p tag populated from text input via keyup event

Tags: jquery, css, pdf

I have this field offered to users that will be used to populate a fixed width cell in a PDF. I would like a way to notify the user when they have hit the maximum width for the PDF cell.

So, I created a div with a p tag (formatted with exact font, size and weight that will be rendered in the PDF) that is populated from the text input on KEYUP event. I know the width of my PDF field is 226.

The p tag (#arial12B) is populating just fine with the code below, but my if statement doesn't seem to be working. All I want to do is turn the background-color of the text input (#custName) to a red color notifying the user their entry is too long.

Code below

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#custName').keyup(function(){
            var desc = $(this).val();
            $('#arial12B').html(desc);

            if($('#arial12B').width() > 226){
                $(this).css('background-color', '#cccccc');
            }
        });
    });
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
   $('#custName').keyup(function(){

      var desc = $(this).val();
      var cache = $(this);

      $('#arial12B').html(desc).promise().done(function(){
        if($('#arial12B').width() > 226){
          cache.css('background-color', '#cccccc');
        } 
      });

   });
```

Comment: hey Raj, I couldn't get this to work, does this code replace all within my keyup function?

Comment: @BillChambers Now try..!

Comment: hey Raj, p tag population still working great but still no text input background-color change.

Comment: can you make a demo of it.? so that we could easily fix that.?

Comment: hey Raj, I haven't ever done a fiddle if that's what you mean?

Comment: Man, I read about .promise and .done and seems you hit it right on the head, like it should work.

Comment: Yes that should work, but i think you need to debug your code, like getting what is the width which is returning from that call back..

Comment: hey Raj, after some debugging I noticed my p tag automatically takes up 100% of its parent div therefore .width() was always 226, so I changed the p tag to a span tag a voila, all works great, thanks for your help.